# Expected Promise<string> but got Promise<string|number> in the error message

Tags: typescript

### Strange type Promise <string|number> in error message

How did the typescript compiler come up with the `Type Promise <string|number> ...` in the error message below.

`Type 'Promise<string | number>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<number>'. Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.`

The code that generates the error message follows below:

```js
const promise: Promise<number> = Promise.resolve(100).then(n => n.toString());
```

### What I thought would happen

I expected `Promise.resolve(100).then(n => n.toString())` to return a `Promise<string>`.
When assigning this to `const promise: Promise<number>`, I expect typescript to show an error message complaining of a mismatch between `Promise<string>` and `Promise<number>`

Instead, typescript somehow adds a `string|number` union and complains that `Promise<string|number>` is not assignable to type `Promise<number>`

Comment: Why are you annotating it as a `Promise<number>` instead of as a `Promise<string>`?  Is that a typo or something?

Comment: My focus for the question is why the typescript compiler determines that `Promise.resolve(100).then(n => n.toString())` resolves to Promise<string|number> ... In order to prove that the typescript compiler does this, I deliberately annotate const promise: Promise<number>

Comment: This still feels like you've got cause and effect backwards; you are making that happen by annotating it this way; if you annotated it as `Promise<Date>` then the compiler would complain about `Promise<string | Date>` not being compatible.  I think there's an interesting question in there about why the error message involves the union of the annotated payload with the actual payload, but you're not asking that question (or at least it's not obvious that you're asking that question).

Comment: Right now the title is like "why does water make me sick" and the question shows that you're drinking water *mixed with bleach*, and your reply here is of the form "In order to prove that water makes me sick I mixed it with bleach". I don't quite know how to proceed with this.

Comment: I have edited my question for clarity. I was interested in the  strange union in the error message as you said .... but mangled my original question.

Comment: So, `Promise.then()`'s [type definition](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/670bc4202e/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1527) has two generic type parameters; one for the success result and one for the reject result, and the return is the union of both of those.  By annotating with `number` the compiler is trying to determine types [contextually](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) to match, ends up inferring `number` as the reject result type, but this yields `string | number` which doesn't work. So you get an error.

Comment: Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer with sources and more of an explanation. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: yes, that answers the question. thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TypeScript call signature](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/670bc4202e/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1540) for [the `then()` method of `Promise` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) is equivalent to:

```
interface Promise<T> {
  then<R = T, E = never>(
    onfulfilled?: ((value: T) => R | PromiseLike<R>) | undefined | null, 
    onrejected?: ((reason: any) => E | PromiseLike<E>) | undefined | null
  ): Promise<R | E>;
}
```

and has *two* [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters that the compiler needs to infer when you call it.  The first type parameter `R` corresponds to the "success" return value for the `onfulfilled` callback, while the second type parameter `E` corresponds to the "error" return value for the `onrejected` callback.  And `then` returns a promise with a payload of [the union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `R | E`.

Normally when you write something like

```
const promise = Promise.resolve(100).then(n => n.toString());
```

without the `onrejected` callback, there is no inference site from which to infer `E`, and the compiler falls back to the [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) type argument of [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), and since `never` is eagerly absorbed by unions, you'd get `R | never`, or just `Promise<R>`, corresponding to the type returned from the `onfulfilled` callback.  So in the above call, `R` is inferred as `string`, and `E` fails to infer and falls back to `never`, and you get `Promise<string>` out, as expected.

But by [annotating](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the type of `promise` as `Promise<number>` in:

```
const promise: Promise<number> = Promise.resolve(100).then(n => n.toString());
```

you are getting different behavior.  You are telling the compiler that you expect a `Promise<R | E>` to be `Promise<number>`, and therefore that `E` can be [contextually typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing).  So `E` no longer falls back to `never`; instead, the compiler tries to choose `E` so that `Promise<R | E>` matches `Promise<number>`... so it chooses `number` (which you can verify if you ask IntelliSense for the quick info about the `then()` call):

```
/* (method) Promise<number>.then<string, number>(
     onfulfilled?: ((value: number) => string | PromiseLike<string>) | null | undefined, 
     onrejected?: ((reason: any) => number | PromiseLike<number>) | null | undefined
): Promise<string | number> */
```

Of course that doesn't work; `R` is still inferred as `string` from the `onfullfilled` callback, and with `E` of `number`, the return type is `Promise<string | number>` which is not assignable to `Promise<number>`, and you get the error

```
// Type 'Promise<string | number>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<number>'.
```

---

So that's the explanation.

Backing up: to some extent it's an implementation detail exactly *which* error message you get when inference fails... in the face of an incompatible type annotation, you know *something* is going to break, but not necessarily the precise nature of the failure.  You didn't expect the compiler to try to use `number` as context for the inference, and so were surprised to see `Promise<string | number>` instead of `Promise<string>`.  But since neither of those types would have worked, it's somewhat academic that the error message mentioned one instead of the other.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgJxAWwJYQKYC4YAUlqYA8YArsgEYYIB8MAvHgehgHQIYQgA2AbhgAoAjAAYRASlZQAFhjACwDOmCkgAylASowAcwHjxAbgBQAegBUMAcgwyQAE3FMULEuSq0pssEWhbdADQwZJTUNALGMFFR4ABmpNyxqNzcGPYA-DgCArwAhtyk2MHu1E70dH7aOjAAPs6EGAAyqADWGL6aVTROdWQptTCkYPYYSWBpQZHRMOAcAFYYwFBpmVYCHLlcYDi5YACeZcolCAP4LpjNbW6htD3F-XVDI2NpxuI4Zw0d-tW9x3TmUzGMymGAAFT2cAwMAA5J9XJVdAMQh4aDCYOhgiBYJsIKgdGBchRUjAoCBSZDoXDmMQUWEYaxgUA)